# Check if a string is in a MySQL field value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a DB field called 'colors' where I store favourite colors from people. These are selected from a multi-select field and I store them all in one field. I use PHP to get all the values in one field using:

```
$lookfor = implode(",", $looking_for);
```

What's the best way to search for a string within a field that contains values in the format red,blue,yellow....

Since the users will use the same multi-select box I still need to access the values in this format.
I tried using

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
 WHERE users_looking_for LIKE '%$lookfor%'
```

But this won't work if my values are not store in the same order as they are searched.

Answer (score 8):

#### Short term solution

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT u.* 
                    FROM USERS u
                   WHERE FIND_IN_SET('%s', u.users_looking_for) > 0", 
                  mysql_real_escape_string($lookfor));
```

If you want to search for more than one lookfor value, you will need to add additional FIND_IN_SET checks:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value1', u.users_looking_for) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('value2', u.users_looking_for) > 0
```

#### Long Term Solution

Do not store denormalized data - use a many-to-many table setup:

#### PEOPLE

- people_id (primary key)

#### COLORS

- color_id (primary key)

#### PEOPLE_COLORS

- people_id (primary key, foreign key to PEOPLE.people_id)
- color_id (primary key, foreign key to COLORS.color_id)

Answer (score 0):

> but this won't work if my valyes are
>   not store in the same order as they
>   are searched.

Sort them before storing, and sort them before searching.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I still couldn't use the LIKE for this.
If I had the values in the field as BLUE,GREEN,RED and search for LIKE '%BLUE,GREEN%', the values above won't get picked up.

Comment: @Bruno follow OMG's solution, he's an expert.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table user_colors with two fields : "user_id" and "color"

This would be much easier to search for values.

example :

```
SELECT * FROM user_colors WHERE color='red' OR color='blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of using a VARCHAR field to hold the list of selected colours, you move to more of a relational approach, where each colour for each user is listed.  That way when you do your query you are able to say where it is IN a set of values which are their selections.